# Nexus 6P wifi issues, wont connect, no internet

Tags: wi-fi, 7.0-nougat, nexus-6p

This hasn't been addressed in other 6P threads. Nexus 6P running Nougat can connect to my 5Ghz Wifi network in my home.

I'll connect to my 5Ghz band of my wifi network, but the status on the phone will either say "connected, no internet" or even "connected" but the internet wont work. Phone shows good signal strength and link speed, but browsing or trying to download anything doesn't work.

Everything on LTE works fine though. And I have other devices connected to my wifi network (on the 2.4Ghz band) and they work fine as well. Plus my desktop has no LAN issues, so I'm guessing it's not a router problem.

[image]

Here are the solutions I've tried thus far with no avail:

- With or without VPN
- 2.4Ghz or 5Ghz bands
- Restarted in Safe Mode, same problem. Will connect to my networks but internet wont work
- Powered off, waited a minute, powered on
- Disabled security authentication for the network on the router
- Re-enabled security authentication
- Factory reset router
- Factory reset Nexus 6P

Comment: I called Google and explained the process I've gone thru. They are sending a new Nexus 6P. We'll see then I guess what the issue was/is. One thing I haven't done yet is try to connect the phone to another network (I dont have any public networks nearby). I'm just going back to the fact that my tablet LAN work just fine that it wouldn't be my router.

Comment: Update: I am at my parents now.. and similar to before, I can connect to their Wi-Fi network with multiple devices, but the internet doesn't work on the Nexus-6P. At least I know it's not the router. Just waiting on that new phone from Google now.

Comment: Update #2: I have received a new 6P from Google, RMA'd my old phone, still under warranty.  I hope to receive feedback on what the root cause of the issue was, but I'm not holding my breath.  The new phone has no issues.

Answer (score 1):

I came across a solution using airplane mode on another forum. The method is turn on airplane mode, then turn WiFi on again. After it settles, turn airplane mode off. I did this and it made a difference. Like it was trying to connect but was still struggling.

So then I noticed that the time was not set correctly. Like it did it was 10am and it was actually 5pm. So quite the difference. I fixed the time and bam! Everything back to normal. I hope this helps some one!

Answer (score 0):

You may have been able to fix it without an RMA, your 6P probably had some artifact in its settings that caused the issue. I had a similar problem where the 6P would not connect to my 2.4GHz network, but it did connect to my 5GHz network.

**The Fix:** In your 'Wireless & Networks' expanded menu, click on 'Network Settings Reset'. This gives you a clean slate to try and reconnect to your networks.

^For anyone else stumbling onto this thread

Comment: why wouldn't this have been fixed with a factory reset?

Comment: Ah my bad, I didn't read his last bullet point.